# Ios simulator still showing deleted view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

Hi i deleted the navigation view called lista but the tab bar still shows the lista icon , and in fact it stills show that view which i deleted previously any suggestions?

[image: It shows the more icon but i deleted the view that had a relationship segue]

[image: There´s the view that i deleted in the storyboard]

Comment: I don't see any Lista icon in the tab bar.

Comment: Where is this UITabBarController created and configured? Is it done in code? if so, show the code. If in the storyboard, is the Lista controller still in the storyboard?

Comment: UITabBarController is the default  everything is configured from the storyboard nothing from code. Lista controller is not in the storyboard .

Comment: This might not work, but try quitting Xcode and then cleaning out the Derived Data folder and resetting the Simulator, as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994 Sometimes old versions of things stick around until you do this.

Comment: You were completely right i just reseted everything and that was all!!!

Comment: Cool! Yes, this is just a shortcoming of Xcode that we all have to live with... :)

Comment: Please Clear derived data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like matt said just reset everything in the simulator i like shown here.
[How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what matt is saying, clear all the derived data and reset the simulator.